# Test Rewarded ad not displaying - Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config.)

Tags: android, flutter, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad, google-mobile-ads

I'm currently unable to display a test rewarded ad. I am using the rewarded ad `Sample ad unit ID` provided in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads): `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917`.

I am getting error code 3, which according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL):

> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Which doesn't seem to make sense as this is a test ad, and should always be available?

**The full error:**

> Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain:
> com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config.) => No ad config.

*For reference, I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/217) on the googleads-mobile-flutter repo with the full log outputs.*

Any ideas why I wouldn't be able to fetch even a test ad?

Also please leave a comment if you've been able to successfully display test rewarded ads or real rewarded ads with this plugin lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: The issue has resolved itself without any changes to the code. I can only assume that there was an issue on Google AdMob's side.

Nonetheless, the answer below still allowed to test ads while the sample ad unit was not working.

If you get here because the sample ad provided [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) does not work, see the rest of this answer for an alternative solution.

---

It seems that using a real ad unit works, as opposed to the sample rewarded ad unit `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917`. Thank you @Kurt Lee Kalbus

I am not sure why the sample ad unit doesn't work at the moment, but it seems like an error from the server.

If you need to test rewarded ads right now, without serving real ads:

- from an Android emulator: use a real rewarded ad unit. This will serve a test ad. As per the  [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads): "Android emulators are automatically configured as test devices."

Otherwise, you should add your device to your list of test devices before using a real ad unit. See [Add your test device in the AdMob UI](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#add_your_test_device_in_the_admob_ui)

Answer (score 1):

I was using the same ad Unit to test two days ago and it was working but not working today with the same error you are having.both the Android Ad unit and the IOS ad Unit so i believe the issue is from the Network.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this exact problem for a week. Finally today I switched it to the real ad id and it worked. It looked like a real ad but at the top it was labeled "Test Ad". Do you think that means I can use it until they fix the real test add or are they going to yell at me?

Comment: It's best to limit your answer to helping the OP. If you have related questions, it's best to start a new post to get help.

Comment: Wow I'll have to try this asap. Unfortunately I can't try it right now with my real account as I need to wait 1-14 days for verification of my payment info... just needed a test ad for my current need so I hadn't put my payment info.

Comment: Also, I think as long as you're using your adUnit on an emulator it shouldn't be a policy violation. As per the [doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads): 
**Key Point: Android emulators are automatically configured as test devices.**

Comment: Good news, a real ad unit worked! Thanks a lot.