# LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config... when trying to load BannerAd in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob

I have an app with the ads, when I run my app in debug mode with the test ad unit, everything works fine. However, when I run the app in release mode with the real ad unit from AdMob, I have an error

```
LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))
```

I'm having this for almost two months, please help me resolve it.

[Here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/307) is a link for a GitHub issue I've opened, refer to it for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test Rewarded ad not displaying - Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442391/test-rewarded-ad-not-displaying-ad-failed-to-load-loadaderrorcode-3-domain)

Comment: Not really, as here, the problem is that they cannot see the ads with testAdUnit, while I can't see it with the real adUnit, but I can see the ads when I use testAdUnits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem and the solution.
The fact that the app was not signed was the cause of
`LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: []))`

[Signing](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) the app have solved my issue.

Comment: Sadly this did not solve it for me.

Comment: Please check if ad mob has placed ad limit on your account

Answer (score 2):

Add your Phone as test device in Google Admob over at the Settings. Then it should work! When releasing to play store make sure to state that your app is using Ads in the console

Comment: You did not understand the question right. My device is added to the test devices, and when it is added, I see the ads, but on a regular phone, installing my app in a release mode, not adding the device as a test device, leads me to this error. My app is already uploaded to the Play Store, and it is already set that the app is going to have ads.

Once again, the problem is, encountering this error, when I want to see the ads as a regular user, installing the release mode of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just check out if your app is not limited by google .

Comment: Can you offer instruction to the OP on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Just look over this , bro. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442391/test-rewarded-ad-not-displaying-ad-failed-to-load-loadaderrorcode-3-domain
I'm struggling with this problem with the test ad unit id , so I can't help you.

Comment: On AdMob's site, in my account, it's written that my account is approved and the ads are being distributed, that makes the situation even more strange

Comment: Did you find out what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just change you app package name and App Id for just testing, Actually sometime google play store limited app of testing Ads based on App id and app Package name

Comment: Hi. I've already found a solution to the problem I had and answered the question here.