# Rewarded ad failed to load flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Getting this error sometimes while loading rewarded ads.

```
     RewardedAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: nu
ll, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})
```

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209488/loadaderrorcode-3-domain-com-google-android-gms-ads-message-no-ad-config) did you sign you app in release mode ? did you try with test device added?

Comment: At first i was getting this error like no config then i try real admob ads now it shows  ads . but sometimes not showing ads

Comment: is you app live and published?

Comment: While the development, you should use `testing admob` ids.
Please refer [this link](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads).